# SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' esmify

Tags: node.js, module, telegram, browserify, telegraf

index.js

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
```

use command  `browserify index.js -o -p esmify > bundle.js`

but I'm getting error

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

But [esmify](https://github.com/mattdesl/esmify) is supposed to handle import / export ES module syntax so I don't know what could be wrong with this

Comment: I'm running in the same problem, did you figure out how to solve it?